# How to prevent clicking on a checkbox's label span. clickable only on checkbox only

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a checkbox in jsp form with label in it containing span which get displayed after inspecting element.i want checkbox to be clickable only when i click on checkbox only.if i  click on checkbox label span it should not be clickable. i am not allowed to modify this tag as it has  dependency in class , also i cannot modify css for it as it gets break on every page.if solution can be done using jquery then most welcome. thank you in advance.

JSP Code

```
<div class="fbox3 nspan">
<form:checkbox path="sendWelcomeEmail"  cssClass="label-revert" checked="true"label="Send a welcome email with login details to the user.  /></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replaced jsp tag with html

```
  <form:form method="POST" commandName="user" action="" id="user-profile-form">

        <div class="fbox3 nspan " id="sendWelcomeEmail">
                                    <input id="sendWelcomeEmail1" name="sendWelcomeEmail" class="label-revert " checked="true" type="checkbox" value="true">
                                    <label for="sendWelcomeEmail1" style="display:inline-block !important;padding-right: 0 !important; "></label>
                                    <span style="display:inline-block; font-family: latolight, helvetica, arial, sans-serif ; font-weight: 300; color: #969696 !important; font-size: 16px;">Send a welcome email with login details to the user.</span>
                                </div>
```

and css

```
#user-profile-form label > span {
margin-right: 12px !important;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$("span").css("pointer-events", "none");
```

Alternative,

```
<span onclick='return false;'>some text here</span>
```

Comment: thank you but i have added as it is in <script> tag and not working.

Comment: span visible only in dev tool so cannot use second option.